# how to change character \ in to -? C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

```
        string s = "P\04";
        string z = s.Replace('\\', '-');
        Console.WriteLine(z);
```

I need to replace **'\'** character in to '**-**' character in a string. I tried several ways to replace, couldn't able to do for '\' character only.
Please any one suggest a way to do this

Comment: `\0` is an escape sequence for the character of numeral value 0. There is no \ in the string to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string s = @"P\04";
 string z = s.Replace('\\', '-');
 Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Add @ at the  before value of string s to make it a verbatim. That way '\' is treated as is. Otherwise \0 are treated as one character to make a different character.

Answer (score 4):

Your code to replace the `\` is fine. The problem is with your input string, where the `\` escapes the `0`. It would work if you had this:

```
string s = "P\\04";
string z = s.Replace('\\', '-');
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

The output is `P-04` assuming that's what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Regex,

```
var result = Regex.Replace(@"P\04", @"\\", @"-");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**[`FIDDLE`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dvy9Y6)**